# How to pass service objects/modules as arguments in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming

Is it possible to use Module or objects as arguments for each method in ruby?

I need something like.

```
module PrintAny
  def call(text)
    puts text
   end
end

["any"].each PrintAny
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost. You can make your module convertable to proc and use it that way:

```
module PrintAny
  def self.print(text)
    puts text
  end

  def self.to_proc
    method(:print).to_proc
  end
end

["any"].each &PrintAny # => prints "any"
```

`Enumerable#each` requires you to pass a block, the ampersand operator (`&`) converts an object to block by first calling `to_proc` on that object. And modules are just objects, hence if they have a method `to_proc`, this will work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see when this can ever be used in real life, but...:

```
['any'].each &PrintAny.instance_method(:call).bind(Object)
#=> any
```